# Failed to upload camera image file on aws s3

Tags: android

Unable to upload image path to s3 in android

```
content:/com.earlysalary.android.provider/external_files/IMG_20180523_164228_1998498766.jpg
```

I am using FileProvider for getting uri of camera image.
getting invalid file exception while try to upload on S3 of above uri.

```
String authorities = mContext.getPackageName();
Uri  imgUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), authorities +".provider", photoFile);
```

For uploading on s3 I am using

```
 File uploadFile = new File(imgUri .getPath());

   TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload("my_bucket", bucketFilePath, uploadFile, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);{

}
```

getting error

```
System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid file: content:/com.example.android.provider/external_files/IMG_20180523_164228_1998498766.jpg
05-23 16:43:45.931 30128-30128/com.earlysalary.android W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility.upload(TransferUtility.java:532)
05-23 16:43:45.931 30128-30128/com.earlysalary.android W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility.upload(TransferUtility.java:497)
05-23 16:43:45.931 30128-30128/com.earlysalary.android W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility.upload(TransferUtility.java:436)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file path is valid and not null. Also, check the correct permissions on accessing your s3 bucket. Mostly this process is straight forward. Check out the link here: http://javasampleapproach.com/android/uploaddownload-files-images-amazon-s3-android

On above link, if you go to section 5.4 Upload file, cross check in your code that you are setting the correct TransferObserver. Code snippet from above link is below:

```
// KEY and SECRET are gotten when we create an IAM user above
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(KEY, SECRET);
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

TransferUtility transferUtility =
        TransferUtility.builder()
                .context(getApplicationContext())
                .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                .s3Client(s3Client)
                .build();

// "jsaS3" will be the folder that contains the file
TransferObserver uploadObserver =
        transferUtility.upload("jsaS3/" + fileName, file);

uploadObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

   @Override
   public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
      if (TransferState.COMPLETED == state) {
         // Handle a completed download.
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
         float percentDonef = ((float)bytesCurrent/(float)bytesTotal) * 100;
         int percentDone = (int)percentDonef;
   }

   @Override
   public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
      // Handle errors
   }

});

// If your upload does not trigger the onStateChanged method inside your
// TransferListener, you can directly check the transfer state as shown here.
if (TransferState.COMPLETED == uploadObserver.getState()) {
   // Handle a completed upload.
}
```